# Are there principal $G$-bundles whose holonomy group is $G$?

Tags: principal-bundles, holonomy

While studying universal constructions on principal bundles, I've stuck on a quite a basic question, namely:

Given a Lie group $G$, does there exist a principal $G$-bundle $\pi \colon P \to B$, for *some* base $B$, that admits a connection $\theta$ whose holonomy group is the full group $G$?

I suppose the answer is yes, but I have no idea of how to prove it.

Comment: I suppose you mean to ask whether there is a principal $G$-bundle $\pi:P\to B$ for *some* base $B$ that has a connection $\theta$ whose holonomy is the full group $G$. (You need a connection to define holonomy.)  If $G$ is connected, the answer is certainly 'yes' as soon as $B$ has dimension $2$. In fact, in the connected case, you can take $B = \mathbb{R}^2$ and the generic connection on $G\times\mathbb{R^2}$ will have holonomy $G$.  If $G$ is not connected, you have to work  a little harder.  More interesting are those $G$-bundles $P$ for which *all* the connections on $P$ have holonomy $G$.

Comment: Yes, that was exactly my question; and that was also the answer I needed, thanks! (I will edit the statement with your correction to make it more precise).

Comment: @RobertBryant: Do you have any nice examples of those $G$-bundles for which all the connections have full holonomy?

Comment: @VítTuček:  Sure.  For example, any $S^1$-bundle over a compact manifold whose first Chern class is nontorsion has no connection whose holonomy is a proper subgroup of $S^1$.  As another example, any $\mathrm{SU}(2)$-bundle $B$ over a compact manifold $M$ whose second Chern class cannot be written as the negative of a square of an element of $H^2(M,\mathbb{Z})$ cannot be given a connection whose holonomy is a proper subgroup of $\mathrm{SU}(2)$.  In general, if the structure group of a principal $G$-bundle $B$ cannot be reduced, then the holonomy of any connection on $B$ must be all of $G$.

Comment: Thanks. I should have known this, since I read Theorem 11.7 of http://www.emis.de/monographs/KSM/ few months ago. :)

Comment: @RobertBryant Sorry if this is silly, but I do not understand your first comment. If you choose the connection on $B\times \mathbb{R}^n$ define by $(u_b,u_g) \to u_g $ (which is what you perhaps mean by the generic connection on the product bundle), should not the holonomy group be ${e}$ rather than $G$ ?

Comment: user90041: The connection that you have written down (if I understand you correctly) is the flat connection, and so, of course its holonomy is trivial.  However, a *generic* connection, even on a trivial $G$-bundle (i.e., a product) over a base of dimension $2$ or more and with $G$ connected, will have holonomy $G$, as I show below in my answer.

Comment: Just adding this in case someone is interested in more "sophisticated examples." Every principal bundle, which is fat, is of such type in the question; see, for instance, the paper of Westein on the subject or the paper "Fatness revisited" due to W. Ziller.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment, when $G$ is connected, you can do this with $B=\mathbb{R}^2$ and $P$ being the trivial bundle $P = G\times\mathbb{R}^2$.

Here is one construction:  Let $\frak{g}$ be the Lie algebra of $G$ and let $\gamma:TG\to\frak{g}$ be the canonical left invariant, $\frak{g}$-valued $1$-form on $G$.  Let $(r,\theta)$ be polar coordinates on $\mathbb{R}^2$, let $f = f(\theta):S^1\to\frak{g}$ be a curve such that there are values $\theta_1,\ldots,\theta_m$ such that the elements $f(\theta_i)$ for $1\le i\le m$ form a basis for $\frak{g}$ and such that $f'$ vanishes in an $\epsilon$-interval about each $\theta_i$ for some $\epsilon > 0$, and let $\rho=\rho(r)$ be a smooth, even function of $r$ that vanishes identically in a neighborhood of $r=0$ but has $\rho'(r)\equiv1$ for $r\ge1$.  Now consider the connection form
$$
\alpha= \gamma + \mathrm{Ad}(g^{-1})\bigl(\rho(r)f(\theta)d\theta\bigr),
$$
where $g:P\to G$ is the projection onto the first factor. (When $G$ is a matrix group, this is just $\alpha = g^{-1}dg +g^{-1}\bigl(\rho(r)f(\theta)d\theta\bigr)g$.)  Then I claim that the holonomy group of this connection is all of $G$.

Since $G$ is connected, it suffices to show that the Lie algebra of the holonomy group is all of $\frak{g}$ because, by Borel and Lichnerowicz, we know that the holonomy is a Lie subgroup of $G$.  To do this, note that the given trivialization is is $\alpha$-parallel along each radial line through the origin $(r=0)$, since, along such a line, $d\theta=0$, implying that $\alpha = g^{-1}dg$ along such a line.  On the other hand, because the curvature is 
$$
d\alpha + \tfrac12[\alpha,\alpha] 
= \mathrm{Ad}(g^{-1})\bigl(\rho'(r)f(\theta)\ dr\wedge d\theta\bigr),
$$
one sees that, if one takes parallel translation starting at $\bigl(e,(0,0)\bigr)\in G\times\mathbb{R}^2=P$ above the curve that goes out along the radial path from $r=0$ to $r=1$ at angle $\theta_i$, goes counterclockwise around the box $[1,1{+}t]\times[\theta_i,\theta_i{+}\epsilon]$, and then returns to the origin ($r=0$) back along the initial radial path, then this will wind up at the point $\bigl(\exp(tf(\theta_i)),(0,0)\bigr)\in G\times\mathbb{R}^2=P$.  (Moreover, $\alpha$-parallel translation of the curvature of $\alpha$ at $(1,\theta_i)$ back to the origin along the radial segment will yield a curvature that takes the value $f(\theta_i)$ at $\bigl(e,(0,0)\bigr)\in G\times\mathbb{R}^2=P$, so the Lie algebra of the holonomy group is all of $\frak{g}$.)

More directly, concatenating $m$ of these 'lassoes' about the points $(1,\theta_i)$ with appropriate values of $t$ will yield an $\alpha$-horizontal curve connecting $\bigl(e,(0,0)\bigr)\in P$ to the point 
$$
\bigl(\exp(t_1f(\theta_i))\cdots\exp(t_mf(\theta_m)),(0,0)\bigr)\in P.
$$
Thus, one can reach an open set in the fiber over $(0,0)$ starting from $\bigl(e,(0,0)\bigr)\in P$ and traveling along $\alpha$-horizontal curves.
Thus, since $G$ is connected, the holonomy of $\alpha$ is all of $G$.