# On Holonomy in (regular) Riemannian Foliations

Tags: riemannian-geometry, foliations, holonomy, lie-groupoids, sub-riemannian-geometry

Right now, I am trying to understanding the role of holonomy fields on Riemannian foliations, which lead me to the following (probably topological) groupoid:
Let $\mathcal{F}\subset M$ be a Rieamannian foliation on a complete Riemannian manifold. We consider the *groupoid of infinitesimal holonomy transformations* $\mathcal{E}\rightrightarrows M$ as the collection of linear isomorphisms of the vertical spaces induced by holonomy transformations. These isomorphisms can be thought in two ways:

1) Given a horizontal curve $c:[0,1]\to M$, it induces a diffeomorphism between a neighbourhood of the leaf through $c(0)$ and a neighborhood of the leaf through $c(1)$. The isomorphism is just the differential of this diffeomorphism.
2) Let $c$ be a horizontal curve as above, then an $h$ is such an isomorphism between the verticals at $c(0)$, $\mathcal V_{c(0)}$, and the verticals at $c(1)$, if it sends $\xi\in \mathcal{V}_{c(0)}$ to $\bar\xi(1)$, where $\bar \xi(t)$ is the holonomy field along $c$ with $\bar \xi(0)=\xi(0)$.

The groupoid structure of $\mathcal{E}$ is the natural on, given by the source and target points of the isomorphism. I would like to know **when $\mathcal E$ admits a smooth structure that makes it a Lie groupoid**.

Please observe that it can't be the general case, since not all pair of points can be reached through a horizontal curve. Therefore, I suggest to assume this hypothesis, together with whatever other hypothesis you feel comfortable (such as bounded holonomy fields, compactness of M - the case of submersions with compact holonomy seems quite simple, so please do not assume it).

Based on Robert Bryant's answer [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/154072/are-there-principal-g-bundles-whose-holonomy-group-is-g), an optimal solution would be some kind of regularity between horizontal curves and the leaves: for example (here we assume that every two points can be connected through a horizontal curve), for each $p\in M$, there is a neighborhood $U$ of the leaf around $p$ and a smooth map $\Phi:U\times [0,1]\to M$ such that, for each $x$, $\Phi(x,t)$ is a horizontal curve starting at $p$ and $\Phi|_{U\times \{1\}}$ is a diffeomorphism of $U$.

I appreciate comments and suggestions.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 'horizontal curve'.  I would guess that you mean 'curve whose tangent vectors are orthogonal to the tangent spaces to the leaves', but I'm not sure.  Could you clarify?

Comment: Sorry for that. Yes, by a horizontal curve I mean a curve whose velocity is always orthogonal to the tangent spaces of the leaves. Analogously, I call 'verticals' the vectors tangent to the leaves. Thank you for the comment!

Comment: What will be the Lie algebroid of this groupoid if the distribution normal to the foliation is not integrable ?

Comment: I do have a positive answer to this question (sort of). Should post it soon.